# Layout Issues Using UIContainerView

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, autolayout, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

I have a view for an IPad app that I just can't get to layout correctly. I'm trying to display two (possibly more in the future) static tables arranged horizontally in a ViewController. Since static tables require a TableViewController, I'm using a UIContainerView to embed each table inside the parent view. All well and good, but when I actually run my app, the first table has a sizable vertical offset while the second table lines up nicely with the top of the container. From what I can tell it seems like the nav bar is doing something with the first child of my container but I have no idea what setting I would need to modify to change this.

As an example, I whipped up a quick Hello World demo that shows the issue I'm running into. Here is the link: https://github.com/pbtura/container-view-example

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: any chance you did not set 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInset' to NO for your viewController ? (the viewController containing the tableViewControllers) - the default for this property is 'YES'

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your test app. This looks like a bug to me. BTW, there's no such thing as a UIContainerView.

Comment: Thank you so much Cabus, that did the trick! If you want to write your comment up as an answer I will mark it as the solution.